# How do I make zip files that unzip cleanly on any OS with native tools?

Tags: zip, self-extracting

If I make a zip file on OSX 10.6 with the OS native tool, and unarchive it on Windows 7, it's root directory will be doubly nested in another one with the same name, and it will contain all kinds of trash like .MACOSX and .ds_store

If I make a zip file on windows with the OS native tool, and try to unzip it on OSX with the native tool, it just creates a .ztgz file or something and then unzipping that just results in another zip file ad infinitum.

How do I make a clean zip file, for distribution, that will work correctly and cleanly on any system?

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting up DOSBOX in a vm and then use Dos to create your .ZIP file.

But before you get to that point, if I were you I would install 7-zip from http://www.7-zip.org/ and use that. 7-zip has lots of options and can create .ZIP files as well as its own format. Since you have access to Windows it is probably easiest to install the Windows .MSI and use the Windows Explorer right-button menu to access the 7zip GUI.

And you could combine both those options, and run Linux in a VM on your OS/X box in order to run the same flexible UNIX tools as OS/X has, but in a simpler environment with less frills and more control.

Answer (score 0):

*Added only as current useful information*

There are utilities like [BetterZip](http://macitbetter.com) [$19.95] that will specifically exclude any platform-specific extras like Mac ._ [dot underscore] files etc.