# What ZIP compression method do common OS's natively support?

Tags: windows-7, macos, windows-8, zip

7-zip gives me 5 options for the compression method to zip files with:

- Deflate
- Deflate64
- LZMA
- BZip2
- PPMd

On my Windows 8 machine, the built-in Windows Explorer utility <strike>appears to handle LZMA with no problem</strike> can *list* the files in an LZMA-compressed file with no problem...but not actually read them. I know Deflate is the most compatible, but for some files I'm attempting to distribute, the maximum setting results in a file that's 2x larger than the LZMA-compressed file. However, because the people I'm distributing it to have whatever OS, I need a widely-supported format.

What compression methods to the native zip utilities on Windows 7, 8, and Mac OS X support?

Comment: If your primary goal is compatibility with all/most OSs and unzipping tools, then Deflate is your best choice.

Comment: LZMA is not native to Mac or Win, but [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html) is available for a large number of platforms. I guess it depends on whether your potential users would already have it, or if the additional download would be less than the difference between LZMA & Deflate

Comment: Related/Possible dupe: [How do I make zip files that unzip cleanly on any OS with native tools?](http://superuser.com/questions/389619/how-do-i-make-zip-files-that-unzip-cleanly-on-any-os-with-native-tools?rq=1)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 The posible dupe is a bit platform- & OS-specific. I'd consider this a new question, & your initial comment actually 'the answer' to it.

Comment: Personally, if the file is big enough to warrant the discussion, I'd hit it with whatever gets the best compression, and provide a link to 7-zip for people who have issues with native tools.

Comment: @Nate If I'm sending something to a client at work, I absolutely need it to open on their computer first try.

Answer (score 10):

If your primary goal is compatibility with all/most OSs and unzipping tools, then Deflate is your best choice.

From [Wikipedia's Zip->Compression Methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)#Compression_methods) article:

> The most commonly used compression method is [DEFLATE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE), which is described in [IETF RFC 1951](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1951).

Comment: Deflate, +1. Be careful of implementations, though. They adhere to RFC 1951 (Deflate) and RFC 1952 (Gzip) to varying levels. See, for example, [The Archive Browser does not honor original filename field in a GZIP header](http://code.google.com/p/theunarchiver/issues/detail?id=802).

Answer (score 7):

Since no one has answered the actual question yet:

> What compression methods to the native zip utilities on Windows 7, 8, and Mac OS X support?

- Windows 7+ supports Deflate and Deflate64.
- macOS only supports Deflate.

Answer (score 1):

Any OS with python 3.3 or above and the zipfile, zlib, bz2 & lzma modules can unpack zip files using Deflate, Deflate64, BZip2 and LZMA compression methods using the [zipfile command line interface](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#command-line-interface), e.g.

```bsh
python3 -m zipfile -e example.zip .
```

Recent versions of macOS and many (most?) Linux distros fulfil this criteria.

Answer (score 0):

In 2020 it seems that still only `zip` + Deflate is acceptable for GUIs, but for automated processes and CLI, you've got a few other options:

## Native CLI Support: tar

- Mac ships with BSD `tar`
- Linux ships with GNU `tar`
- Windows 10 ships with BSD `tar.exe`

They all support `tar.gz`.

BSD tar also supports `.zip` (but not LZMA, unless `xz` is also installed, which it is not on Windows 10, as of 2020).

`zip` support is native on MacOS, and pretty easy to get on Linux.

## Cross-Platform: arc

If it's reasonable to have someone use a utility that's easy to install and that supports xz (LZMA, same as 7z), [arc](https://github.com/mholt/archiver) is lightweight and can be installed without a platform-specific package manager - meaning no brew: [bare download](https://github.com/mholt/archiver/releases) or via [webinstall](https://webinstall.dev/arc).

```bsh
arc unarchive example.tar.xz
```

It also supports several other common formats: `zip`, `xz`, `tar.xz`, `tar.gz`, `tar.bz2`, etc.

Comment: The bit about `tar` etc. does not appear to clearly address the question. Also there is no standard `tar` in Windows, so such is less portable without additional tooling.

Comment: tar.exe (BSD Tar) has been available as part of the native Windows CLI tooling since the last update of 2017: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/containers/tar-and-curl-come-to-windows/ba-p/382409

Comment: Generically speaking tar is a form of zip in the same way that 7-zip and WinZip are a form of zip. Tar and WinZip both have a "none" option for compression, and both support other forms of compression too.